# Read a file with an edge list for a graph and create adjacency list in Python

Tags: python, adjacency-list

My program creates a complete graph, prints the edges, and then creates an adjacency list. However, it's not efficient. I would like for the program to:

1. print the edges list into a text file and then
2. have the Create Adjacency List portion of the program to read that edge list file and print the adjacency list. Currently, I hard code the edge list into the program which is not efficient because I need to have the ability to change V to test different runtimes.

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create complete graph
complete_graph = nx.complete_graph(10)
plt.subplot(121)
nx.draw(complete_graph, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

#list edges -----I want this to output to a file instead
list(complete_graph.edges)

# A class to represent the adjacency list of the node 
class AdjNode: 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.vertex = data 
        self.next = None
  
# A class to represent a graph. A graph 
# is the list of the adjacency lists. 
# Size of the array will be the no. of the 
# vertices "V" 

class Graph: 
    def __init__(self, vertices): 
        self.V = vertices 
        self.graph = [None] * self.V 
  
    # Function to add an edge in an undirected graph 
    def add_edge(self, src, dest): 
        # Adding the node to the source node 
        node = AdjNode(dest) 
        node.next = self.graph[src] 
        self.graph[src] = node 
  
        # Adding the source node to the destination as 
        # it is the undirected graph 
        node = AdjNode(src) 
        node.next = self.graph[dest] 
        self.graph[dest] = node 
  
    # Function to print the graph 
    def print_graph(self): 
        for i in range(self.V): 
            print("Adjacency list of vertex {}\n head".format(i), end="") 
            temp = self.graph[i] 
            while temp: 
                print(" -> {}".format(temp.vertex), end="") 
                temp = temp.next
            print(" \n") 
  
  
# Driver program to the above graph class. -----> instead of coding each edge, I'd like for main to 
# read the edge text file created earlier to create the Adjacency List. 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    V = 10
    graph = Graph(V) 
    graph.add_edge(0, 1) 
    graph.add_edge(0, 2) 
    graph.add_edge(0, 3) 
    graph.add_edge(0, 4) 
    graph.add_edge(0, 5) 
    graph.add_edge(0, 6) 
    graph.add_edge(0, 7) 
    graph.add_edge(0, 8)
    graph.add_edge(0, 9)
    graph.add_edge(1, 2)
    graph.add_edge(1, 3)
    graph.add_edge(1, 4)
    graph.add_edge(1, 5)
    graph.add_edge(1, 6)
    graph.add_edge(1, 7)
    graph.add_edge(1, 8)
    graph.add_edge(1, 9)
    graph.add_edge(2, 3)
    graph.add_edge(2, 4)
    graph.add_edge(2, 5)
    graph.add_edge(2, 6)
    graph.add_edge(2, 7)
    graph.add_edge(2, 8)
    graph.add_edge(2, 9)
    graph.add_edge(3, 4)
    graph.add_edge(3, 5)
    graph.add_edge(3, 6)
    graph.add_edge(3, 7)
    graph.add_edge(3, 8)
    graph.add_edge(3, 9)
    graph.add_edge(4, 5)
    graph.add_edge(4, 6)
    graph.add_edge(4, 7)
    graph.add_edge(4, 8)
    graph.add_edge(4, 9)
    graph.add_edge(5, 6)
    graph.add_edge(5, 7)
    graph.add_edge(5, 8)
    graph.add_edge(5, 9)
    graph.add_edge(6, 7)
    graph.add_edge(6, 8)
    graph.add_edge(6, 9)
    graph.add_edge(7, 8)
    graph.add_edge(7, 9)
    graph.add_edge(8, 9)
    
    graph.print_graph()
```

Output:

```
Adjacency list of vertex 0
 head -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 

Adjacency list of vertex 1
 head -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 0 

Adjacency list of vertex 2
 head -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0 

Adjacency list of vertex 3
 head -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 

Adjacency list of vertex 4
 head -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 

Adjacency list of vertex 5
 head -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 

Adjacency list of vertex 6
 head -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 

Adjacency list of vertex 7
 head -> 9 -> 8 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 

Adjacency list of vertex 8
 head -> 9 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 

Adjacency list of vertex 9
 head -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0
```

Comment: Hi! What format do you want for your output? Should it be exactly like: `Adjacency list of vertex 5 head -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0`
Or you wouldn't mind against something like this: `{5:[9,8,7,...]}`?

Comment: Hi @ValeriiBoldakov, the only thing I need in the output are the pointers "->". To take your example: {5:[9 -> 8 -> 7....]}

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to complete what you want will be serializing and deserializing it with json.

You will have a method in `Graph` like this:

```py
import json

def serialize(self) -> str:
    graph = {}
    for i in range(self.V): 
        temp = self.graph[i]
        tmp_list = []
        while temp:
            tmp_list.append(temp)
            temp = temp.next
        graph[i] = json.dumps(tmp_list).replace(",", "->")
    return json.dumps(graph, indent=4)
```

It will return strings formatted like the following one:

```json
{
    "3": "[1->2->3]",
    "5": "[1->2->3]"
}
```

You can save it to the file or do whatever you want.

For the deserialization we will need another method:

```py
@staticmethod
def deserialize(serialized: str) -> "Graph":
    serialized = serialized.replace("->", ",")
    graph_dict = json.loads(serialized)
    V = len(graph_dict)
    graph = Graph(V) 
    for src in graph_dict.keys():
        for dest in  graph_dict[src]:
            graph.add_edge(src, dest)
    return graph
```

The more authentic way to do it would be to write your own serialization format and to parse it back in deserialization with the [Interpreter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) or to write a grammar and parse with [lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark).

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. How would I call either method to print the list?

Comment: @starrena
You would use:  `graph: Graph =  Graph(V)` to create the graph. Then add edges to it in the usual way. To obtain a string representation to print or to write to file you would use:
` serialized: str = graph.serialize()` and you can print with `print(serialized)` or write to the file. To deserialize it use: `des_graph: Graph = Graph.deserialize(serialized)`.